# .htaccess 301 redirect for substring of URI - it's appending the $_GET['variables'] on the end of the URI

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I just set up a new site and spelled one of the categories as `autimobiles` instead of `automobiles` - I know it's rediculous.  I set up an `.htaccess` 301 redirect for any URL containing the substring `autimobiles` to be redirected to `automobiles`.  So, the URI `/autimobiles/BMW-pictures` should be redirected to `/automobiles/BMW-pictures`.  However, this is what is happening...

This

`http://imageocd.com/autimobiles/hupmobile-touring-pictures-and-wallpapers`

is redirecting to this

`http://imageocd.com/automobiles/hupmobile-touring-pictures-and-wallpapers?one=autimobiles&two=hupmobile-touring-pictures-and-wallpapers`

Here's how I have the `.htaccess` set up.

I have two `$_GET['']` variables entitled `$_GET['one']` && `$_GET['two']` for mod rewrite.  Those two variables are being displayed as `$_GET['']` variables in the URI upon redirection.  I want to remove the `?one=autimobiles&two=hupmobile-touring-pictures-and-wallpapers` from the URI.

Here's my `.htaccess`.

```
# Important line HERE
RedirectMatch permanent autimobiles(.*) http://imageocd/automobiles$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?one=$1&two=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?one=$1 [NC,L]
```

**Update in `.htaccess`**

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^autimobiles(.*)$
RewriteRule ^autimobiles(.*)$ http://imageocd.com/automobiles$1 [R=301,L]

#load-data (2) -- index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?one=$1&two=$2 [NC,L]

#load-data (1) -- index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?one=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: How to remove "?one=autimobiles&two=hupmobile-touring-pictures-and-wallpapers" From the end of the URL.  The redirection works, but it appends bot get variables on the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i correctly understand your question... This code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^autimobiles/(.*)$ http://temp/automobiles/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirect from `/autimobiles/BMW-pictures` to `/automobiles/BMW-pictures`.

EDIT:
You wrote: `How to remove "?one=autimobiles&two=hupmobile-touring-pictures-and-wallpapers" From the end of the URL. The redirection works, but it appends bot get variables on the URL`.

If u want to delete this tags only on this path with automobiles.. so get this one statement to your lines:

```
RewriteRule ^autimobiles(.*)$ http://imageocd.com/automobiles$1 [R=301,L]

#load-data (2) -- index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^automobiles(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?one=$1&two=$2 [NC,L]

#load-data (1) -- index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^automobiles(.*)$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9-]+) index.php?one=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: That's the right idea, but it doesn't work.  It's not redirecting "/autimobiles/BMW-pictures" to "/automobiles/BMW-pictures"

Comment: Also, I replaced "auautimobiles" with "automobiles" and "temp" with the "sites name"

Comment: and notice - this only line doing 301 redirect. erase your `.htaccess` file other commands and insert only this lines. Also `http://temp/` replace with your domain name.

Comment: I updated my .htaccess in my question as with the update; it's no working.  But, I need the other two rules for the mod-rewrite.

Comment: with your code below two blocks `#load-data` - **they** add this `GET` parameters! So if u delete this lines or comment with `#` everything will work fine! Try it.

Comment: I did and have it configured exactly as it's displayed in the update of my answer.  It didn't redirect and the whole site crashes when I remove the mod-rewrite.  I have about 70,000 urls depending on the re-write at this point.

Comment: i checked right now on virtual server. it works fine for given url sample.